# \upharpoonright problem

Tags: symbols, arrows

Sometimes `\upharpoonright` prints the "restriction" (as it is supposed to do) on the output text file, but sometimes it prints horizontal bars (on top of the line) - which I don't know how to correct. 
How can I always get the "restriction" arrow?

```
\begin{corollary} 
Suppose $A \subseteq B$ and $C$ is a club in $P_\kappa B$. 
Then $C \upharpoonright A$ includes a club of $P_\kappa A$. 
\end{corollary}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Can you please take a small screenshot and upload here? You don't have the privileges to post a picture yet. But remove the `!` in front of the link after uploading and we will fix it for you.

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal working example illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: The problem is a bit mystical: the same code put in the beginning of a file outputs correctly, but its copy at the end outputs falsely. I use WinEdit 6.0. the code is e.g.  
\begin{corollary} Suppose $A \subseteq B$ and $C$ is a club in $P_\kappa
B$. Then $C \upharpoonright A$ includes a club of $P_\kappa A$.
\end{corollary}

Thank you guys very much for concerning yourself with my question!

Comment: With [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb), both `\upharpoonright` and `\restriction` are defined as `\mathchar"3416`. To see this add `\show\upharpoonright` and `\show\restriction` in you code and check your `.log` after you compile. Do this at the start of your document (correct output) and at the end (incorrect output) to see if there's a difference. Also, some other packages define these commands, so perhaps add `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass` and add everything after `**File List**` in your `.log` to your post via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/40661/edit).